# jQuery function only on certain pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

I'm trying to trigger a function for different wordpress pages.

I would like a different "slice" of my jquery accordion to open dependant on the page which is loaded.

I have tried

```
if ( is_page( 'sea-freight' ) )
        $(".va-slice-1").click();
```

Is there something wrong with my function?

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">

            <div id="va-accordion" class="va-container" style="width: 100%!important; height: 450px;"> 
                <div class="va-nav">
                    <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                    <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
                </div>
                <div class="va-wrapper">
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-1">
                        <div class="va-title">Airfreight</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Henry Watson</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-2">
                        <div class="va-title">Seafreight</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Keith Johnson</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-3">
                        <div class="va-title">Satellite Tracking</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Andrew Alaniz</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-4">
                        <div class="va-title">Guarding</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Ben Freeman</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-5">
                        <div class="va-title">Machine Moving</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Alex Schuman</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-6">
                        <div class="va-title">Investigations</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Maria Wales</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="va-slice va-slice-7">
                        <div class="va-title">Transport</div>
                        <div class="va-content">
                            <p>Paul White</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/FSI5/jquery.vaccordion.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                       $(function() {
                $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                    visibleSlices   : 5,
                    expandedHeight  : 250,
                    animOpacity     : 0.1,
                    contentAnimSpeed: 100
                });

if ( is_page( 'sea-freight' ) )
        $(".va-slice-1").click()
            });


        </script>
```

Comment: `is_page` is a `php` function?

Comment: yes, I think it is.  I got that from  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66066/can-i-include-javascript-jquery-in-a-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not echoing it. Try

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'sea-freight' ) )
   echo ' $(".va-slice-1").click();'; ?>
```

**[EDITED]**
Also you need to add the php tags.

Comment: Thank you so so much    This is perfect.  Can I just add that same code underneath for other pages as well?

Comment: sorry, one more tiny thing.  After these adjustments (working great for all pages) - it seems that when the page loads, one of the slices show up quickly at the top while the page loads... should my function perhaps be moved or something?

Comment: Need more information on what you are experiencing there. Apparently this code should not impact your display when the page is loading because it is only executed when the DOM is ready.

Comment: my accordion used to load 'from top to bottom' - but now as it loads, slice "7" shows quickly at the top of the page and then it jumps to the correct slice.  I can pm  you the link if possible?

Comment: A solution would be to add display:none to the css of .va-slice and then use $('.va-slice').show() at the end of your jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if (is_page('sea-freight')): ?>
$(".va-slice-1").click();
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this, but it throws out my page with an error message?

Comment: Can you provide this message? Or, maybe, you can post a link?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know, maybe is_page() it is function of engine that you use. if dont, browsers haven't that basic js function, you can build your own on javascript

```
function is_page(page){
    if(page==window.location.pathname){
        return true;
    }
return false;
}


if ( is_page( 'sea-freight' ) )
    $(".va-slice-1").click()
        });
```

print somewhere console.log(window.location); and watch what it contains

Comment: js function was corrupted, i suggested js answer =)